# Cannot import app from app (Unknown Location) Flask

Tags: python, flask

Terminal Dump -

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'microblog', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iglu/repos/personal/Flask Mega Tutorial/microblog/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/iglu/repos/personal/Flask Mega Tutorial/microblog/microblog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (unknown location)
```

File Structure-

```
├── app
│   ├──  __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── microblog.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── routes.py
├── microblog.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── microblog.cpython-39.pyc
├── README.md
└── venv
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

routes.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

microblog.py

```
from app import app
```

The python variable is indeed set to the venv one image

Python 3.9.5 Flask 2.0.1 Werkzeug 2.0.1

Any help would be great! I have tried my best to follow the guide precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your file structure, python is **in no way** going to know that `microblog.py` **exists**. That's because, when you type `from app import app`, python will **look for the package `app`**

Now, your `microblog.py` is **not a part of the package** `app`. So, try moving it **inside the app folder** (more precisely a package because **any folder having init is called a package**) and it will work fine.

Comment: Uhh, I may have fixed it already. It was just a typo in the __init__.py file name, it has a space. My file structure worked :P.

Comment: oh fine. Initially, I thought it was because of the way you were accessing microblog.py within your app. Either ways, glad that you got it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it was a typo it was just a typo in the init.py file name.

Cannot close so uhh consider it closed